# Stack build times out buiding an ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

When creating a new stack the build hangs building this ECS service then eventually times out. I can find no message as to why the build never completes. Is there an error in this?

```
  webService:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::Service"
    Properties: 
      Cluster: !Ref webCluster
      DesiredCount: 1
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: web 
          ContainerPort: 80
          LoadBalancerName: !Ref webLoadbalancer
      ServiceName: web
      TaskDefinition: !Ref webDocker
      Role: !Ref ECSrole
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is timing out and not failing because of any other error, it is probably worth checking if the "DesiredCount" which is set as 1 for this Task definition is ever getting achieved.

For a quick check could you set the DesiredCount as 0 in the cloudforamtion template and then try to get the service running manually once the ECS cluster and services are set by Cloud formation?

If by setting the Desired Count as 0 works, there could be various reasons why the container was not coming up for desired count as 1, some of these reasons could be:

1) No instance attached to the ECS cluster?

2) Not enough CPU and memory available for the task to run, worth checking the CPU and soft limit set in the task definition in that case.

3) Port conflict in the instance?

Please have a go with Desiredcount as 0 and then manually set it as 1 later and try to find out the reason from the task definition logs.